# How to validate Session in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to create a session in Codeigniter. I have loaded `session` and `encrypt` library in autoload. By default the `login.php` page opens. I want to open the `dashboard.php` page, if the user is already logged in. I have written the following code,  but it opens the login.php page, even after login.

Kindly tell me how to check if the session is already set or not.

> ```
>  public function index()
> {          
>    $data['products_data']= $this->products_model->all_products(); 
>            //   $this->load->view('login');
>
>    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
>    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
>
>     if ($this->form_validation->run()== false)
>    {
>        $this->load->view('login');           
>    }
>    else
>    {
>         if ($this->session->userdata('login_status')) {
>
>             $this->load->view('header');
>             $this->load->view('dashboard');
>             $this->load->view('footer');
>
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             $username=   $this->input->post('username');
>             $password=   $this->input->post('password');  
>
>              if( $this->products_model->login_model($username,$password))
>              {
>                $sess_data= array(
>                                 'username'=> $username,
>                                 'login_status'=>'1'
>                                 );
>
>                 $session_data   =   $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);                    
>
>                 $this->load->view('header');
>                 $this->load->view('dashboard');
>                 $this->load->view('footer');
>
>              }
>
>         }
>    }
>
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sessdata = $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
if (isset($sessdata))
{
//session exists
}
else{
// no session value
}
```

So Your controller should look like below to avoid redirecting to login page on page refresh,

```
function index() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('login_status')) {
        //write your code for redirect to dashboard
    } else {
        $data['products_data'] = $this->products_model->all_products();
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

            $this->load->view('login');
        } else {
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            if ($this->products_model->login_model($username, $password)) {
                $sess_data = array(
                    'username' => $username,
                    'login_status' => '1'
                );
                $session_data = $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
                //write your code for redirect to dashboard
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code. Still after login when i refresh the page it sends me back to login.php..and now after login its opening a blank page. Kindly check it. Thanks

Comment: `if($this->products_model->login_model($username,$password))
{ }else{//your login code}`. Check your if condition is true or false. After its true, then only the session validation will be checked.

Comment: @AftabAamir check my answer, your `$sess_data` on `set_userdata` has a single qoute remove it, because it is treating it as a regular string

Comment: @AftabAamir else part in your code is not written for `isset($sessdata)`. Its written for your `login_model()`.

Comment: I have update my code, now its successfully login and open the dashboard.php, but still when i revisit login.php , it open the login form, and doesnot redirect me  to the dashboard.

Comment: @AftabAamir Just echo a sample text inside if( $this->products_model->login_model($username,$password)){} then try whether it prints or redirect to login form. If it redirect to login page , then if( $this->products_model->login_model($username,$password)) condition is false. Not if ($this->session->userdata('login_status')) condition

Comment: I have updated my code, i have written all the code in `index Controller`, but still when i enter username & password, it prints the line but when i refresh the page it again shows me the login page.

Comment: @AftabAamir I think values for $username and $password are not passed / empty when you are refreshing the page.

Comment: @AftabAamir Check the Updated answer You will understand why your page is redirect to login page on page refresh.

Comment: I have updated my code, but still its giving me the same output as before

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45641/discussion-between-aftab-aamir-and-balajimca)

Answer (score 1):

I rather like to create another controller for dashboard and redirect it to there after successful login. It is clean and you can do further changes easily

```
if( $this->products_model->login_model($username,$password))
{
    $sess_data= array(
        'username'=> $username
    );

    $session_data   =   $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);

    if(isset($session_data))
         redirect(site_url('/dashboard/'));

}
```

FM: $sess_data should not be in single quotes

Comment: If i use redirect then how would i load the header and footer views?

Comment: Write following code in your index function of dashboard controller

$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('dashboard');
$this->load->view('footer');

so when you land there, header and dashbaord and footer will be loaded

Answer (score 1):

I will use session to record login status.

```
$session_data= array(
    'username'=> $username,
    'lgoin_status' => 1
);

$this->session->set_userdata('$session_data');
```

And I will check session's `login_status`

```
if ($this->session->userdata('login_status')) {
    // do something
}
```

**Edit**

On your code, you should check session at first, so..

```
public function index()
{   
   if ($this->session->userdata('login_status')) 
   {
      // do something
   }
   else 
   {

   $data['products_data']= $this->products_model->all_products();  

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

   if ($this->form_validation->run()== false)
   {
       $this->load->view('login');           
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my code, now its successfully login and open the dashboard.php, but still when i revisit login.php , it open the login form, and doesnot redirect me to the dashboard.

Comment: You can check session on your `login` controller's `index` or `contructor` method, and redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single qoutes on

`$this->session->set_userdata('$sess_data');`

it is treating the variable `$sess_data` as a regular string.

must be:

`$this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);`

Comment: Thank you, I have update my code, now its successfully login and open the dashboard.php, but still when i revisit login.php , it open the login form, and doesnot redirect me to the dashboard.